Reorder number N to become the largest number divisble by M
Suppose I have the number N, with 1 <= N <= 10^15. I want to reorder the number so that you get the largest number possible and it is divisible by M.( M is any even number less than 12)
E.g: N = 4264, M = 8 then the largest number divisible by M made by the digits of N is 6424
This is my code:
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
s = list(map(int,list(str(n))))
s.sort(reverse=True)
# missing part here
print("".join(map(str, s)))

I am missing the part to reorder the digits of N.
Can someone help me?

The "missing part" is basically the entire code.

Also, your example is wrong.

Largest, Smallest? You say both in different places  Which is it?

Do you have limits for M as well?

"M is any even number less than 12" - So it can be -42?

You simply need to define a function to check the divisibility of a number by a given integer:
import itertools

def smallest_divisible_by_m(digits, m):
    digits.sort()
    for perm in itertools.permutations(digits):
        if perm[0] == 0:
            continue
        num = int(''.join(map(str, perm)))
        if num % m == 0:
            return num
    return None  
n = int(input("Enter N: "))
m = int(input("Enter M: "))

digits = list(map(int, str(n)))

result = smallest_divisible_by_m(digits, m)
if result is not None:
    print("The smallest number formed by the digits of", n, "that is divisible by", m, "is", result)
else:
    print("No valid number formed by the digits of", n, "is divisible by", m)


Here is the output of your example:


I tried this with n = 10**10; m = 3. That already took 17 seconds. I think for their 10^15, it would take over 100 days :-(

Btw, you convert the digits to ints but don't do anything with them other than to compare with 0 and to convert them back to strs a lot. That's wasteful. Better just keep them as strs. With that, my above test "only" took 8.5 seconds.

Note this question has changed, and now it is asking for the largest multiple of M (it seemed to be the smallest) and limiting M to even numbers less than 12 (there were no limitations on M). So a few parts of my answer don't apply any more. However I decided to leave the answer as I had originally written it because I think being more general it is more interesting this way. But while most of the suggested implementations still apply, it must be noted that the "different approach" doesn't make sense any more with the new version of the question.
As noted in comments, while the accepted answer is obviously correct and well written, the execution time will quickly become very long when we deal with larger values of N and no solutions. As stated in comments, even avoiding some int/str conversions we get 8.5 seconds to check for a no solutions case with a 10 digits value of N, cause we check for 10!, or 3628800, permutations before failing. With a 15 digits N we'll have to check for 15!, or 1307674368000, permutations, and at the same speed that would mean more than 35 days. So let's see some possible optimizations.
Distinct permutations
As N grows there is an increasing probability that some digits will appear more than once, and with 15 digits we'll have a minimun of 5 duplicated digits.
The distinct_permutations() function from the more_itertools library is almost as fast as the standard itertools.permutations(), but avoids generating multiple instances of the same permutation when you have repeating elements. This will reduce the number of permutations by a factor of 2! for each duplicate digit, a factor of 3! for each triplicate digit, and so on. So with 5 duplicates we are reducing the number of permutations to check by a factor of 2!**5, or 32 - our run time is now one day and something, not one month. And if we were lucky enough to have say 4 instances of a digit and 3 of another we would speed things up by a factor of 4! * 3!, or 72.
Divisibility by 3, or 9
What we are doing here is looking for a permutation P of the digits of N such that P is divisible by M. Suppose that M is divisible by 3: then P must be divisible by 3 as well. Since a number is a multiple of 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is a multiple of 3, we know that all the permutations, including N, are divisible by 3, or no one is. So if M is a multiple of 3, and N isn't, we know that no solutions exist and we can immediately return. This shortcut will work for one third of all possible Ms paired with two thirds of all possible Ns, so it immediately solves some 22.2% of all possible cases; and those cases are all worst cases, i.e. cases with no solution.
We can go one step further, because if both M and N are divisible by 3 we can check divisibility by 9: if M is a multiple of 9 and N isn't we have another few cases we can immediately solve, bringing the total just short of 25%
Divisibility by 10, 5, or 2
Once again, if M is divisible by some number D, all its multiples are divisible by D too. A number is divisible by 10 if and only if it ends with 0, so if N doesn't contain any 0s we cannot have a solution. This is not going to happen frequently, especially with larger numbers, but it is worth a try anyhow. But the interesting part is, we can pull one instance of 0 from our list of digits, compute the permutations of the remaining digits, and just append our 0 at the end of each: for a 15 digits N this is a 15x speed up. On the other hand, it must be noted that if we had more than one 0, removing one of them reduces the gain given by the distinct_permutations(). For instance if we had three 0s in the original list, we were having a 6x reduction, but now we only have a 2x. So the actual further gain we get in this case is just 5x (15*2/6); but the accumulated gain is still quite interesting.
A similar reasoning can be applied when M is divisible by 5: our P needs to end with 0 or 5, so if N doesn't contain any instances of those digits we have no solutions; if it only contains instances of one of those digits, we can do the same trick we used with D = 10; finally, if N contains instances of both digits we'll need to iterate twice, once moving a 0 at the end, and once moving a 5.
And the same holds when M is even, though in this case we'll need to consider all of 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 as allowed final digits. In some edge cases however this could even slow down our computation: suppose N contains 2 instances of all the even digits: since we need to iterate on all 5 digits our 15x speed up becomes a mere 3x, while we're losing the 32x guaranteed by the distinct permutations optimization. So it would be probably better to have our procedure evaluate how many iterations we need and which repeating groups we scale down, and check if this optimizations is still worth applying.
A different approach
While all of the above helps reducing the execution time in many cases we will still have to wait many hours before we get a "no solution" answer. Let's try something different, and consider the "lenghts" of M and N, i.e. the number of digits in each.
If N is shorter than M then all permutations will be lower than M, so no solutions.
If the two numnbers are of equal length, we iterate on all the multiples of M starting with M itself until we find a number which contains exactly the same digits of N, and then we have the solution, or which is greater than the highest permutation of N (the digits of N in reversed order), and then we know there is no solution. This will require less than 10 iterations.
If N is "longer" than M we do the same, starting form the first multiple of M as "long" as N, and again exiting the loop when we find a solution or get a number higher than the highest permutation of N. For a difference in length of 1 digit this will again require less than 10 iterations, and in general for a difference of x digits this will require less than 10**x iterations.
For small values of x this approach will be much faster, But since we can easily predict both the maximum nunber of permutations needed by the first method, and the maximum number of iterations needed by the second one, our code should include a check to evaluate which method is best.

"almost as fast as the standard itertools.permutations()" - What do you mean with that? I just tried, permuting 10 elements took ~40 times longer with distinct_permutations(). (About 4 seconds vs 0.1 seconds.)

Ok, probably "almost as fast" is not the best expression, although on my machine a timeit of for p in permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]):pass with 10 runs gives around 1.18 secs, while the same with distinct_permutations gives 14.76, so it would seem a 12.5x slowdown, not 40x. But what I meant is, the slow part here is not generating the perms but processing them, so the delay introduced is neglectable compared to the benefit

I consumed with minimal overhead, the usual deque with maxlen=0. What time do you get when you replace pass with del p? But yes, I agree it's probably neglectable in the overall program.
